# popover on hover not working on second page of datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, popover

I added content of one column dynamically...

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   data.referred_by='<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" class="" title="'+temp[i].referred_by+'"data-trigger="hover" data-content="Total Referrals :'+temp[i].as_count+'">'+temp[i].referred_by+'</a>'
 }
```

and Following code is of creating datatable

```
$('#datatable4').dataTable({
  'paging':   true,  // Table pagination
  'ordering': true,  // Column ordering 
  'info':     true,  // Bottom left status text
  "aaData" : data,

  aoColumns: [
    { mData: 'index' },
    { mData: 'patient_name' },
    { mData: 'age' },
    { mData: 'gender' },
    { mData: 'mobile_no' },
    { mData: 'email_id' },
    { mData: 'request_status' },
    { mData: 'referred_by' },
    { mData: 'ref_to_img'},
    { mData: 'ref_by_img'}
  ]
```

and in ready function I added

```
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

but in datatable only on first page popover on hover is working... and on second page onwards its not working.... is there any solution for this?

Comment: Could you include your HTML? Further context might help. Consider setting up a demo with https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to reinitialize the popovers each time the dataTable is redrawn.     `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()` will only initialize those popovers visible at the time the code is executed, not the popovers in for example page #2. Execute `popover()` in the [**`drawCallback()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) callback instead :

```
$('#datatable4').dataTable({
  ...
  drawCallback: function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  }  
})
```

Comment: not work for drawCallback: function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  }

Comment: @WahyuKodar `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` will certainly work if  you have `data-toggle="tooltip"` included in your tooltip elements.