# Popover not working with my Datatable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatable, popover

i am trying to display a pop over on my Data Table,
on my data table each cell containing a href and what i want is while clicking on that href i want to display some data from data base. i am using nodejs with jade.

here is my data table code,

```
script.
    var report;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var col = [
            {data: 'client_name'},
            {
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<b>Code:</b>'+'<a class="popover-success popover-scale" id="t_branch" data-toggle="popover" data-content="test content" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Success" >' + full.branch_code +'</a>';
                }
            },
            {
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<b>Serial: </b>'+'<a id="t_router" href = "#" >' + full.router_serial + '</a>';
                }
            },
            {
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<b>Serial: </b>'+'<a id="t_data_card" href = "#" >' + full.data_card_serial + '</a>';
                }
            },
            {
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<b>Sim No: </b>'+'<a id="t_sim" href = "#" >' + full.sim_number + '</a>';
                }
            },
            {
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return'<b>Serial: </b>'+'<a id="t_idu" href = "#" >' + full.idu_serial + '</a>';
                }
            },
            {
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<b>Serial: </b>'+'<a id="t_modem" href = "#" >' + full.modem_serial + '</a>';
                }
            },
            {data: "installed_date"},
            {data: "ip_address"},
            {
                defaultContent: "", render: function () {
                return "<a id='download'  >Download Report</a>";
            }
            },
            {data: "notes"}
        ];

        //ArrayCreation
        var ddata = !{JSON.stringify(dispatched_data)};
        //alert(JSON.stringify(ddata));
        var dataset = [];

        for (var k in ddata) {
            dataset.push({
                "client_name": ddata[k].client_name,
                "branch_code": ddata[k].branch_name,
                "router_serial": ddata[k].router_serial,
                "data_card_serial": ddata[k].data_card_serial,
                "sim_number": ddata[k].sim_number,
                "modem_serial": ddata[k].modem_serial,
                "idu_serial": ddata[k].idu_serial,
                "installed_date": ddata[k].installation_date,
                "ip_address": ddata[k].ip_address,
                "ir_report": ddata[k].ir_report,
                "notes": ddata[k].notes
            });
        }
        //alert(JSON.stringify(dataset));
        //alert('After: '+JSON.stringify(dataset));
        var thistable = $('#example').DataTable({
            deferRender: true,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller: true,
            paging: true,
            info: false,
            data: dataset,
            columns: col,
            dom: 'lfrtip',
            order: [[1, "asc"]]
        });
```

i tried a lot.. but cannot figured out anything.. i am new to web development.

Comment: Judging from your syntax, you are trying to use bootstrap. Did you include the accompanying tooltip plugin as described on the bootstrap page?

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36384326/4050261

Comment: Possible duplicate of [popover on hover not working on second page of datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371215/popover-on-hover-not-working-on-second-page-of-datatable)