# Bootstrap Tooltip doesn't work on previously hidden columns of DataTable

Tags: bootstrap-4, datatables, tooltip

I have a DataTable on which each cell has a Bootstrap Tooltip. Some of the columns are initially hidden and can be made visible by the user as per the Column Visibility option of DataTables. The now visible columns contain the HTML required for the tooltips, however the Bootstrap Tooltips do not show up on them and instead the regular standard tooltips show up.

What causes this and how could I fix this?

An example of my issue can be seen here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.dataTable').length > 0) {



        $('.dataTable').DataTable({
            lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, "ALLE"]],
            pageLength: 10,
            dom: 'Blfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'colvis'
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: "hidden",
                    visible: false
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/libs/datatables/latest/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">


    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Visible 1</th>
                <th>Visible 2</th>
                <th>Visible 3</th>
                <th class="hidden">Hidden 1</th>
                <th class="hidden">Hidden 2</th>
                <th class="hidden">Hidden 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr onclick="auftragModal({{ auftrag|json_encode }})">
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 2">V2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V3</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 1">H1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 2">H2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden3">H3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr onclick="auftragModal({{ auftrag|json_encode }})">
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 2">V2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V3</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 1">H1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 2">H2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden3">H3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr onclick="auftragModal({{ auftrag|json_encode }})">
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 2">V2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V3</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 1">H1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 2">H2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden3">H3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hu3fLr2e/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure what caused the issue, I fixed it by also calling `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` on the `column-visibility.dt` event. New example below should work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.dataTable').length > 0) {



        var table = $('.dataTable').DataTable({
            lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, "ALLE"]],
            pageLength: 10,
            dom: 'Blfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'colvis'
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: "hidden",
                    visible: false
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    table.on( 'column-visibility.dt', function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    } );
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/libs/datatables/latest/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">


    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Visible 1</th>
                <th>Visible 2</th>
                <th>Visible 3</th>
                <th class="hidden">Hidden 1</th>
                <th class="hidden">Hidden 2</th>
                <th class="hidden">Hidden 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr onclick="auftragModal({{ auftrag|json_encode }})">
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 2">V2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V3</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 1">H1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 2">H2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden3">H3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr onclick="auftragModal({{ auftrag|json_encode }})">
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 2">V2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V3</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 1">H1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 2">H2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden3">H3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr onclick="auftragModal({{ auftrag|json_encode }})">
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 2">V2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visible 3">V3</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 1">H1</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden 2">H2</td>
              <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hidden3">H3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The popovers in datatables which are not visible in initial drawing doesn't work.
And initialization each time is necessary.
So your solution seems good!
Similar Problem: [popover on hover not working on second page of datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371215/popover-on-hover-not-working-on-second-page-of-datatable)

Comment: This is more suitable for a comment - I know you cannot comment yet, so you should post valuable questions and answers to stack up your reputation first! Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for telling. As you said, this should be a comment.